# Meaning of "Put me down" and "course" in one sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> - Hey, Mr. Peanutbutter. You wanna go fly a kite?
> - **Put me down for** a supersized "sounds great" but **with an even larger main course** of "sadly, I cannot." I'm swamped here at work.

Well, I think Mr. Peanutbutter is trying to say that it's a great idea but he can't do it due to work but he said this in a very complicated way that made me think of it for a long time to be able to know what he's trying to say.

- What's the meaning of "put me down for"? Why doesn't he simply say "sounds great"?
- Also I don't understand the second bolded part. I know course means tutorial or a series of lessons. So what's the meaning in the context here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a really strange conversation. It's a mish-mash of idioms, an extended metaphor revolving around so-called "fast food".

**Put me down for** means, literally, "write my name down as wanting (something)".

> We're going to go get some donuts. Any requests?
>   -- Put me down for chocolate.

Now, with respect to "supersized"...

> a supersized "sounds great"

In the US, drinks at fast-food restaurants and convenience stores are sold in various sizes. Some are nearly the size of a bucket. They are "super-size".   There is even a verb now used by people who work at fast-food restaurants or who eat at them:

> OK. One Coke. Do you want me **to supersize** that?

It means, do you want me to change the order from regular size to "supersize"?

So, a **supersized "sounds great"** would mean "A very big "Yes!" The "yes" has been supersized.

However, there is a **but** in the statement.

> ... but with an even larger main course of "sadly, I cannot."

The "main course" is the main part of a meal.  So, although his "yes" was big, his "no" must be even larger, and the size is again being cast in terms of a fast-food menu.

P.S. This sounds like a conversation from a badly written sit-com.

Comment: P.P.S. It's from an [animated series](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=bojack-horseman-2014&episode=s02e10), evidently.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, you're right. I'm trying to learn an advanced level of English using this funny series.

Comment: Well, that kind of English is about as good for you as fast food and supersized drinks would be :)

Answer (score 2):

You're right that it is a complicated, and very chatty, way of saying it.

"Put me down for" something means literally  "Put me on the list of people who are going to get something" - to buy something, go to some event, join some club. It really doesn't mean much here - perhaps "I will subscribe to ..."

You've got the wrong meaning for "course". "Main course" means one course of a meal (starter, main course, dessert etc). Again, it really doesn't mean much here.